# Google sheets: Count Specific Characters in a string of words

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have on Google sheets this data (It is the same principle in excel).

I want to count the numbers of dose in each strings.

I use this formula and it return me this:

```py
=LEN(L3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(L3,"/",""))
```

| Product | dose | Count "/" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 0 |
| 2 | 5G | 0 |
| 3 | 10G/20G/24g | 2 |

I would like instead in returns me this :

| Product | dose | Count "/" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 5G | 1 |
| 3 | 10G/20G/24g | 2 |

How I can modify my formula to return me this?

Comment: 1+ your formula where dose is non-blank

Comment: Well, if there is any text then it must be 1, so an if() would do that then the count has to be your formula plus 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B),LEN(B2:B)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B,"/",""))+1,""))
```

Or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B),LEN(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"[^/]",""))+1,""))
```